# Why vibration doesn't work on Android P (API 28)?

Tags: android, kotlin, vibration, android-9.0-pie, haptic-feedback

I'm trying to implement haptic feedback when changing a value of a seekbar.
It works correctly on Android pre-P. On Android P it doesn't work at all.
Code:

```
private val vibrator = context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator?
private val effect by lazy { VibrationEffect.createOneShot(VIBRATION_DURATION, 50)}
...

fun vibrate() {
    if (vibrator == null || !vibrator.hasVibrator()) {
        return
    }
    vibrator.cancel()
    vibrator.vibrate(effect)
```

Answer (score 6):

It turns out the user has to enable Touch vibration in Settings -> Accessibility -> Vibration -> Touch vibration:[image]

Without it, short vibration (less than 5 seconds) won't work. For me, this is not quite intuitive, so I decided to post it here

Comment: This is a very unfortunate design!  Is there any way to check that setting programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

exactly what Mike said.
but for android Pie - Setting->Sounds and vibration -> System sounds and vibration -> Touch vibration

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vibrate(VibrationEffect vibe, VibrationAttributes attributes)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator#vibrate(android.os.VibrationEffect,%20android.os.VibrationAttributes))

(Note: Before API level 33 you need to use AudioAttributes instead of Vibration Attributes)

By setting the Usage of the VibrationAttributes/AudioAttributes for example to USAGE_NOTIFICATION you should at least have a vibration that is enabled by default. The user can still turn off the notification vibrations in the settings though.